# How does this 3 of a kind beat the opponents full house?

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand

[image: I only have a 3 of a kind, while opponent has a full house, why do I get the majority of the money?(The opponent went all in if that matters)]

I only have a 3 of a kind, while opponent has a full house, why do I get the majority of the money?(The opponent went all in if that matters)

Comment: what site was this on?

Comment: Without knowing the site, but it looks like one of those mobile apps for fun and likely could view a side pot win as a win. It looks to me that on the corner there is another player with cards showing, and likely your 3 of a kind beats them for the side pot. It looks like the fullhouse has won the main pot of 179$ and you have won the side pot for 4,389$